# Queueing mechanism and Elasticsearch 1.4.0

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have a RabbitMQ broker, on which I post different messages that will end up as documents in Elasticsearch. There are multiple consumers from the broker, which are actually different threads in a task executor assigned to an amqp inbound gateway (using spring integration and spring amqp here).

Think at the following scenario: I have created a doc in ES with the structure

```
{
   "field1" : "value1",
   "field2" : "value2"
}
```

Afterwards I send two update requests, both updating the same field, let's say `field1`. If I send this messages one right after another(common use case in production), my consumer threads will fetch the messages in the right order(amqp allows this), but the processing could happen in the wrong order and the later updated value could be overwritten by the first one. I will end up having wring data.

How can I make sure my data won't get corrupted? =>Having 1 single consumer thread is not enough, because if I want to scale out by adding more machines with my consuming app, I will still end up having multiple consumers. I might need ordering of messages, but having multiple machines I will probably need to create some sort of a cluster aware component, I am using SI, so this seems really hard to do in my opinion.

In pre 1.2 versions of ES, we used an external version, like a timestamp, and ES would have thrown `VersionConflictException` in my scenario:first update would have had version 10000 let's say, the second 10001 and if the first would have been processed first, ES would reject the request with version 10000 as it's lower than the existing one. But from the latest versions, ES guys [have removed this functionality](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5661) for update operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to use multiple queues and have a single consumer on each queue; use a hash function to always route updates to the same document to the same queue see the [RabbitMQ Tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html) for the various options.

You can scale out by adding more queues (and changing your hash function).

For resiliency, consider running your consumers in [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/). You can have a single instance of each rabbit source (for each queue) and XD will take care of failing it over to another container node if it goes down.

Otherwise you could roll your own by having a warm standby - inbound adapters configured with `auto-startup="false"` and have something monitor and use a `<control-bus/>` to start a new instance if the active one goes down.

**EDIT:**

In response to the fourth comment below.

As I said above, to scale out, you would have to change the hash function. So adding consumers automatically while running would be tricky.

You don't have to hard-code the queue names in the jar, you can use a property placeholder and fill it from properties, system properties, or an environment variable.

This solution is the simplest but does have these limitations.

You could, however, build a management app that could scale it out - stop the producer, wait for all queues to quiesce, reconfigure the consumers and restart the producer - Spring Integration provides a `<control-bus/>` to start/stop adapters; you can also do it via JMX.

Alternative solutions are possible but will generally require maintaining some shared state across a cluster (perhaps using zookeeper etc), so are much more complex; and you **still** have to deal with race conditions (where the second update might arrive at some consumer before the first).

Comment: How can I inject this hash function with spring-amqp? Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: Just compute the hash from the document somehow, e.g. `customerNumber % 3` (if 3 queues) and use it to build the `routingKey` in the `rabbitTemplate.send...(...)` method(s).

Comment: Let's say I post to 3 different queues and I register 1 consumer for each of the queues. If I have 3 machines that hold my app deployed, how can I ensure that only one thread will fetch messages from a queue?

Comment: One thread per listener container (inbound-channel-adapter) is the default; it is controlled by the `concurrency` attribute. However you must not hand off to another thread - process on the container thread; don't use any `QueueChannel`s or `ExecutorChannel`s etc.

Comment: My question was different: Assume I have 3 queues: q1,q2,q3 and 3 runnable jars which represent consumers. In each runnable jar I will define an inbound channel adapter or an inbound gateway and here I have to specify the queues I'm listening on. I have to hardcode the queue names and put in the first consumer q1, the second q2 and so on. Is this assumption correct? And how I can scale out automatically? I think I have to manually do the deployment and make sure which runnable jar listens on which queue. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default mechanism for consistency checks. Basically you want to verify that you have the latest version of whatever you are updating.

So for that you need to fetch the _version with the object. In queries you can do this by setting version=true on the toplevel. That will cause the _version to be returned along with your query results. Then when doing an update, you simply set the version parameter in the url to the value you have and it will generate a version conflict if it doesn't match.

Nicer is to handle updates using closures. Basically this works as follows: have an update method that fetches the object by id, applies a closure (parameter to the update function) that encapsulate the modifications you want to make, and then stores modified object. If you trap the still possible version conflict, you can simply get the object again and re-apply the closure to the object. We do this and added a random sleep before the retry as well, this vastly reduces the chance of multiple updates failing and is a nice design pattern. Keeping the read and write together minimizes the chance of a conflict and then retrying with a sleep before that minimizes it further. You could add multiple retries to further reduce the risk.

Comment: This implies a get call for every update operation.And what if there are concurrent updates on the same document, happening at intervals of ms? Wouldn't this lead to corrupt data? Another question: you have 2 update requests on the same field. You would want the second to be the latest one applied. With this retry, isn't there a change that your first update will be applied last?

Comment: If you have concurrent updates going on, you need in any case to ensure you have the latest version before you overwrite whatever is there. The best way is a doing a GET just before you PUT. In our case, if we don't do that, we quite a few version conflicts under load. There is indeed a chance concurrent updates will get applied in a different order than expected. All this pattern guarantees is that 1) you are updating the version in es. 2) no other updates get written at the same time. It's a form of optimistic locking. You can put additional checks in the closure of course.